# values of diff keys to concatenate from a resource file, how?

Tags: asp.net, resource-files

I want to concatenate the values of two or more keys from a resource file, while assigning value to a control, something like

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLeadTitle" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txtLeadTitle"
    ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, PleaseEnter%>
                      <%$ Resources:LocalizedText, LeadTitle%>"  >
```

but, getting an error. Is it possible some way to concatenate the value of different keys from a resource file?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%# GetLocalResourceObject("ClassKey", "ResourceKey")  & GetGlobalResourceObject("ClassKey", "ResourceKey") %>
```

[HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149948.aspx)

[HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.getlocalresourceobject.aspx)